# How to rewrite Laravel Vendor Auth Methods inside Controller?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

i have web application using larave.
my unique filed in users table are "username" and not "email", i change the files

[image]

[image]

But now every time that i will upgrade Laravel framework this files will deleted, and all of my code.
how can i rewrite this functions in my Controllers?

/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/ForgotPasswordController.php
/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/ResetPasswordController.php

so no meter if the vendor file will updated , my code will still remain?

thanks!

Comment: If you use the same method names in the controllers they'll be overriden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the same name of the function in your own custom controller to override the function used in Laravel's Auth trait.